# C# - Put controls in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, checkbox

I have 30 checkboxes (cb1, cb2,... ,cb30) that I need to be checked programmatically based on a variable value. So, when the var value is 12, I need the checkbox1 to checkbox12 to be .checked = true;

I really have no Idea how to get it work
Please help

Thank you

Edit:
I tried aghilpro's suggestion but I got errors:

```
        reader1.Read();
        if (reader1.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            label5.Text = "Nothing yet";
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = reader1.GetString(0).ToString() + " Times";
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader1.GetInt32(0); i++)
                {
                    Controls["checkBox" + i.ToString()].Checked = True;
                }
            }
        }
        koneksi.Close();
```

Here's the output:

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: please add some html and code for reference..

Comment: it's actually in C#

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at the [tour] (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: winforms or asp? add your code first

Comment: Yes, but still you will have some html where check box are binding and you will also have method where you need to do this code, so add both for reference..

Comment: @Bharat There is no Html if he is working with winforms.

Comment: @jumper0x08 in that case He need to bind at least snapshot of screen..

Comment: Do you want to access the checkboxes by index?

Comment: owhh man.. I have no idea how to post my code in a comment... x_X.. I'm sorry..

Comment: @AndreRio You can edit your question and add some info..otherwise no one can help you..

Comment: @Bharat: I renew the post mate.. thx mate..

Comment: Similiar question is answered for making multiple panels visibile/invisible.. check here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332748/panel-control-with-variable-name/46333052#46333052

Comment: @AndreRio : check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051494/check-all-checkboxes-in-checkboxlist-with-one-click-using-c-sharp

Comment: Done.. it really solve it.. thx a lot @Bharat... cheers!! :)

Comment: @AndreRio cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the Control to a CheckBox. Hint: Not all controls have a Checked property. I hope this make sense. One question to ask yourself is the following. What would happen if you had a button called "checkBox9"?

```
var checkBox = (CheckBox)(Controls["checkBox" + i.ToString()]);
checkBox.Checked = True;
```

Comment: As described in your answer, I would use (Controls["checkBox" + i.ToString()]) as Checkbox to avoid issues if e.g. a button is named "checkbox9". A null-check is required to handle/ignore the button.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [vidstige](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377204/1974344) is correct, but I would use the ['as' operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as).

The 'as' operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, 'as' returns null instead of raising an exception.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (Controls["checkBox" + i.ToString()]) as CheckBox;
if(checkBox != null)
{
   checkBox.Checked = True;
}
```